# Axis 2 web service core 1.1 error wanting a non-existant webapp folder

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis, axis

I have a brand new Eclipse Luna installation with Java EE edition. 
I have Tomcat 7 and axis2 up and running and all working.

In Eclipse 'Window->Preferences->Web Services->Axis2 Preferences' I have set the runtime (to 'C:\DATA\dev\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\webapps') and get the message 'Axis2 runtime loaded successfully'.

However, when I create a new dynamic web project, select 2.5 as the module version (as I read 3.0 doesn't work with axis 2), select Axis 2,

Failed while installing Axis 2 Web Service Core 1.1
The runtime has not been set
go to web services preference page and set the axis 2 runtime.

The error message itself says
The Axis2 facets cannot be installed since the Axis2 runtime location has not been set:
C:\DATA\dev\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\webapps\webapp (The system cannot find the file specified)

So I'm guessing there's a mismatch in the preferences and what the dynamic webservice wizard is doing? i.e. it wants a .\webapp folder after this, but then if I do that the wizard will want to look, in .\webapps\webapp\webapp

surely I'm doing something wrong because this bug would have been spotted and I'm using standard Tomcat installation.

also, if axis is deprecated and was deprecated so long ago, why is Axis still the default web service library?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I picked another folder for axis2 that didn't have the name 'webapps' in it and it worked, so I'm guessing it's a bug in the Axis 2 Eclipse plugin?